# To what depth has chess been solved?

Tags: theory

Starting from the starting position, how many moves deep have we analyzed the possible continuations?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How far from solving chess are we?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/19460/how-far-from-solving-chess-are-we)

Comment: chess is being solved backwards.  There are now Endgame table bases for 6 or 7 pieces I believe.  We don't know what the best first move is at this point.

Answer (score 3):

Chess doesn't work like that. It isn't "solved" from the start position. It is "solved" from the end.

Currently chess has been "solved" for all positions where there are 7 or fewer pieces on the board.

Comment: Just to avoid misunderstanding, "7 pieces" here means two kings plus 5 pieces (of either color).

Answer (score 2):

Are you talking about Perft (https://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/Perft%20Results)? Take a read on the article.

Don't use "solved", that's why you're getting negative votes, use "Perft".

To my knowledge, we have searched every single possibility up to depth of 15. Nobody has done 16 yet.